# Appearing overly emotional while speaking with line manager

Tags: employer-relations

I work in a small startup in the EU, and was teleconferencing with my line manager. I was on the train so connection was not so great and I was off video.

However, as I had just learned about a family member's illness, even though I was not emotional about what my line manager and I were discussing, I could not stop thinking about my family member, and my voice broke more than once. I think he might have either thought that I was crying or that I was emotional about what we were discussing.

We were speaking about my role in his team (we are a three person team), so it can be construed as though I was emotional about that, which I was not.

I do not want him to think that I am an overly-emotional person, or that I get emotional about my work (it's just a job). How do I mend any false impressions of myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People may have stuff going on in their lives, and most people tend to be understanding of that. The manager connecting your voice tone to what you were discussing directly is pretty unlikely, he might even assume you had bit of a cold. I would not worry about it too much.

The best way to not appear as emotional about your work is simply doing your job and keeping your feedback about the work to business itself only. In other words, the best way to give the impression of being logical about your work is being logical with your work over time.